# IEEE 754 arithmitic on 4 bytes(32 bits)

Tags: c, coding-style, floating-point, byte, ieee-754

I wrote this code to do the IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic on a 4byte string.

It takes in the bytes, converts them to binary and with the binary I get the sign, exponent, and mantissa and then do the calculation.

It all works just about perfectl, 0xDEADBEEF gives me 6259853398707798016 and the true answer is 6.259853398707798016E18, now these are same values and I wont have anything this large in the project I'm working with, all other smaller values put the decimal in the correct place.

Here is my code: 
    float calcByteValue(uint8_t data[]) {
       int i;
       int j = 0;
       int index;
       int sign, exp;
       float  mant;

```
   char bits[8] = {0};
   int *binary = malloc(32*sizeof *binary);
   for (index = 0;index < 4;index++) {
      for (i = 0;i < 8;i++,j++) {
         bits[i] = (data[index] >> 7-i) & 0x01;
         if (bits[i] == 1) {
            binary[j] = 1;
         } else {
            binary[j] = 0;
         }
      }
      printf("\nindex(%d)\n", index);
   }

   sign = getSign(&(binary[0]));
   mant = getMant(&(binary[0]));
   exp = getExp(&(binary[0]));

   printf("\nBinary: ");
   for (i = 0;i < 32;i++)
      printf("%d", binary[i]);
   printf("\nsign:%d, exp:%d, mant:%f\n",sign, exp, mant);

   float f = pow(-1.0, sign) * mant * pow(2,exp);
   printf("\n%f\n", f);
   return f;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

int getSign(int *bin) {
   return bin[0];
}

int getExp (int *bin) {
     int expInt, i, b, sum;
     int exp = 0;

     for (i = 0;i < 8;i++) {
        b = 1;
        b = b<<(7-i);
        if (bin[i+1] == 1)
           exp += bin[i+1] * b;
     }

     return exp-127;

}

float getMant(int *bin) {
   int i,j;
   float b;
   float m;
   int manBin[24] = {0};
   manBin[0] = 1;
   for (i = 1,j=9;j < 32;i++,j++) {
       manBin[i] = bin[j];
       printf("%d",manBin[i]);
   }
   for (i = 0;i < 24;i++) {
      m += manBin[i] * pow(2,-i);;
   }
   return m;
}
```

Now, my teacher told me that there is a much easier way where I can just take in the stream of bytes, and turn it into a float and it should work.  I tried doing it that way but could not figure it out if my life depended on it.

I'm not asking you to do my homework for me, I have it done and working, but I just need to know if I could of done it differently/easier/more efficiently.

EDIT: there are a couple special cases I need to handle, but it's just things like if the exponent is all zeros blah blah blah.  Easy to implement.

Comment: the "string" could just be the 4 bytes of a 32bit float, in which case you'd just cast those 4 bytes to be a float, e.g. `f = (float)str`.

Comment: @MarcB, I think it's worth pointing out that if `str` is a string (i.e a pointer to it), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
    unsigned char val[4] = {0, 0, 0xc8, 0x41};
    cout << val << endl;

    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    float f = *(float*)&val;

    cout << f << endl;
    return 0;
```

Comment: Can't believe I was doing it the hard way.  Derp.  I'm always over thinking things.

Comment: This is little endian BTW.  Actual byte value = 0x41c80000

Answer (score 1):

The teacher probably had this in mind:

```
char * str; // your deadbeef
float x;
memcpy(&x, str, sizeof(float));
```

I would advise against it, for the issues with endianness. But if your teacher wants it, he shall have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a union - just create a union where one member is a 4 character array, and the other a float. Write the first, then read the second.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what your code does then the "4 byte string" looks like it already contains the binary representation of a 32 bit float, so it already exists in memory at the address specified by `data` in big endian byte order.

You could probably cast the array `data` to a float pointer and dereference that (if you can assume the system you are running on is big endian and that data will be correctly aligned for the float type on your platform).

Alternatively if you need more control (for example to change the byte order or ensure alignment) you could look into type punning using a union of a uint8_t array and a float. Copy the bytes into your union's uint8_t array and then read the float member.

Comment: I'm just a poor little endian.  I'm gonna try doing the union thing though.

Comment: @JamesCameron: In that case (assuming you create the union as I mentioned) all you need to do is copy the bytes from `data` to the uint8_t array in the union in reverse order and return the float member.